# Android Force GPS location

Tags: android, gps, location, overriding

I want to set a GPS location by surfing around the Google Maps and set my phone location to that location over riding the in-built GPS data.

Is it possible to do it ?
I saw a similar app which does it. just curious how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link.

http://www.geekmind.net/2009/10/how-to-enable-fake-gps-on-android.html

and tell me if this is what you are looking for.

**UPDATE**

this one looks more close to what you have mentioned

http://www.anddev.org/map-problems-f26/fake-gps-location-on-real-device-t11614.html

Comment: i am able to set the fake location on the device as per the links. but when i try to see that as my default location on the google maps it doesnt show. any idea how to make sure the mockup location is constantly the one we set ?

Comment: opened a new thread with the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282965/android-mock-gps-location

Answer (score 0):

check for "Fake GPS" in the Market.

Tschau...Thomas

Comment: yeah i think thats the app i checked out. i want to know how its done.